# What does this infinite sum represent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a better way to write the following?

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^i \frac{\left(\dot{f}\right)^i}{f^{2i-1}},$$

where $\dot{f} = df/dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $$ \dfrac{f^3}{f^2 - (2/3) \dot{f}}$$
whenever the infinite series converges.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** you can write
$$\left( \dfrac{2}{3} \right)^i \dfrac{(\dot f)^i}{f^{2i-1}} = \left( \dfrac{2}{3} \dfrac{\dot f}{f^2} \right)^i \cdot f$$
so, presuming the sum converges, what you have is a geometric series.